# Export results with outreg2

Tags: stata

I am using the *community-contributed* command `outreg2` in Stata to create a table with multiple regressions based on categorical variables:

```
bysort Sector: outreg2 using results_by_sectors.xls, replace dec(2) ///
keep(log_tfp_leader_growth years_schooling_normalized ///
tfp_gap_years_school_norm i_rd_go tfp_gap_i_rd) title("Regressions By Sectors") ///
label: reg log_tfp_growth log_tfp_leader_growth years_schooling_normalized ///
tfp_gap_years_school_norm, robust
```

Everything is well except one thing; the table instead of using the names/labels of the categorical variable Sector pops out as `Sector 1`, `Sector 2`, `Sector 3` and so on:

[image]

However, the labels/names of each Sector are:

```
tab Sector

        ind |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
      10-12 |        236        3.88        3.88
      13-15 |        236        3.88        7.76
      16-18 |        236        3.88       11.64
         19 |        220        3.62       15.26
      20-21 |        220        3.62       18.88
      22-23 |        236        3.88       22.76
      24-25 |        220        3.62       26.38
      26-27 |        220        3.62       30.00
         28 |        220        3.62       33.62
      29-30 |        220        3.62       37.24
      31-33 |        220        3.62       40.86
          A |        284        4.67       45.53
          B |        284        4.67       50.20
        D-E |        252        4.14       54.34
          F |        284        4.67       59.01
          G |        284        4.67       63.68
```

How should I modify my `outreg2` code so instead of getting `Sector 1`, `Sector 2` in the column names of each regression to get the labels of each Sector as shown above (e.g. `10-12` etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with `outreg2` because it is coded by its author to return the name of the variable plus the factor level number:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. bysort foreign: outreg2 using myfile, side replace: quietly reg price weight mpg
dir : seeout

. type myfile.txt
        (1)     (2)     (3)     (4)
        foreign 0               foreign 1       
VARIABLES       price   se      price   se

price                           
weight  4.415***        (0.948) 5.156***        (0.881)
mpg     237.7*  (139.0) -19.78  (57.68)
Constant        -13,285**       (5,726) -5,066  (3,203)

Observations    52              22      
R-squared       0.483           0.785   
Standard errors in parentheses                          
*** p<0.01, ** p<0.05, * p<0.1
```

You can see that this is indeed the case if you `recode` the variable you use for `bysort`:

```
. recode foreign (0 = 1) (1 = 2)
(foreign: 74 changes made)

. bysort foreign: outreg2 using myfile, side replace: quietly reg price weight mpg
dir : seeout

. type myfile.txt
        (1)     (2)     (3)     (4)
        foreign 1               foreign 2       
VARIABLES       price   se      price   se

price                           
weight  4.415***        (0.948) 5.156***        (0.881)
mpg     237.7*  (139.0) -19.78  (57.68)
Constant        -13,285**       (5,726) -5,066  (3,203)

Observations    52              22      
R-squared       0.483           0.785   
Standard errors in parentheses                          
*** p<0.01, ** p<0.05, * p<0.1
```

However, you can get the desired output with the `estout` *community-contributed* command:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. quietly bysort foreign: eststo: quietly reg price weight mpg

. esttab, label nodepvar

----------------------------------------------------
                              (1)             (2)   
                         Domestic         Foreign   
----------------------------------------------------
Weight (lbs.)               4.415***        5.156***
                           (4.66)          (5.85)   

Mileage (mpg)               237.7          -19.78   
                           (1.71)         (-0.34)   

Constant                 -13285.4*        -5065.8   
                          (-2.32)         (-1.58)   
----------------------------------------------------
Observations                   52              22   
----------------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

Obviously, you will have to play with the various options to get exactly what you need (e.g. specify the option `cells(b se)` in order to include standard errors in the table).

Comment: Thank you. You saved an extremely important amount of time. Now, I have to convince the IT people in my company to install such package in the STATA :)